# Pass object to Query.EQ in MongoDb csharp driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

How to pass `Object` to MongoDb query builder?

```
public IMongoQuery Equals(string name,object value){
    return Query.EQ(name, **value**); //compilation error, 
                                     //no overloaded method and no implicit overloading 
                                    //operator for object
}
```

If we are just passing primitive variables `int, double` etc. they have overloaded implicit operator in `BsonValue` class for all primitive types. I wondered if there's a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IMongoQuery Equals(string name, object value)
{
   var val = BsonValue.Create(value);
   return Query.EQ(name, val);
}
```